# Oracle, casting collection to type of existing table

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, polymorphism, multiset

Can I do somthing like this in Oracle 11g:

```
select cast(multiset( select * from table_name) as table_name%TYPE) from dual;
```

in plain sql, without pre-defining type? Is it supports something like polymorphism?

Comment: CAST/MULTISET examples: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions016.htm#SQLRF00613

Comment: i'm especially interested in this construction `table_name%TYPE`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the bigger question is what do you want to achieve here.  According to [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions021.htm),

> MULTISET informs Oracle Database to take the result set of the
>   subquery and return a collection value

So in your example (if modified correctly) you're returning multiple rows and putting them into a collection.  This could be of various forms (varray, nested table, table of objects, etc), but the goal would be to populate your collection from a query, and then USE the collection (which is why I say the big question is what do you want to do/achieve ultimately).

Comment: I'll explain, I want to receive complex object, it is just simple sample. This is what i really want:
select t1.*, cast(multiset( select * from t2 where t2.id=t1.id ) as t2%TYPE) from t1

Comment: still doesn't make sense.  t2 is a table. so you want all the columns from t1 + what?  if you want all the columns from t2, then why not just: select t1.*, t2.* from t1, t2 where t1.id = t2.id;  If you want t1.* + x rows from t2 in each returned row from t1, then you'll need a nested table collection.

Comment: That is what about I said, I need a nested table collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example I copied from somewhere a while ago and kept it for my references. Maybe this will help you:

```
-- The following objects create the basis of the example that follows:
CREATE TABLE projects 
 (employee_id NUMBER, project_name VARCHAR2(10))
/

CREATE TABLE emps_short 
   (employee_id NUMBER, last_name VARCHAR2(10))
/

CREATE TYPE project_table_typ AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10)
/

 -- The following example of a MULTISET expression uses these objects:
 SELECT e.last_name,
   CAST
 (
  MULTISET(SELECT p.project_name
      FROM projects p 
     WHERE p.employee_id = e.employee_id
   ORDER BY p.project_name)   AS project_table_typ  -- here's your %TYPE --
 ) 
 FROM emps_short e
 ORDER BY e.last_name
 /
```

Comment: Thanks, I known this. My question was: "without pre-defined type", in other words, without type declaration. With runtime typing.

Comment: I do not think this is possible as CAST applies to collection-type values only.